# Removing an email from a Django User

Tags: python, django

When in Django I try the following with a Django user:

```
user.email = None
user.save()
```

I get the exception:

```
NOT NULL constraint failed: auth_user.email
```

How does one go about deleting a user's email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Django, a User is defined as follows:

```
email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), blank=True)
```

Consequently, a user's email can be blank (i.e. `""`) but not null (i.e. `None`).  You clear a user's email with the following:

```
user.email = ""
user.save()
```